# How should one refer to their social network profiles in prints?

Tags: social-media, social-interfaces, printing, addresses

In case a person has many different social network profiles, what is the proper way of referring to those profiles in a work that is meant to be printed or may be viewed as an image?

For example one owns the username "CoolCompany" on Facebook, Twitter, Google+ and other websites.

Should they provide a URL for each profile? for example:

```
Facebook.com/CoolCompany
Twitter.com/CoolCompany
...
```

I often see in videos or on TV that people only use the logos but I believe it is not very useful, specially in case that the audience are unfamiliar with a social network.

Is it acceptable to provide the logos or names of the networks and mention the username only once like this:

```
Facebook & Twitter: @CoolCompany
```

Or

```
Facebook & Twitter: /CoolCompany
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the U.S., a few years ago when social media was starting to boom, advertisers would often display a logo and state something like "Find us on Facebook" in TV and print media. However they started to realize that fan pages and other non-official profiles made that confusing, so then they started displaying full URL's (i.e., `www.facebook.com/CoolCompany`)

Now that these social media sites are commonplace in society, it's expected that most know the URL's to get to Facebook and Twitter, so for quick recognition they usually just have a logo followed by `/Coolcompany` for Facebook and `@CoolCompany` for Twitter, to the right or below the logos.

I have seen multiple logos with the same URL path also (i.e., just one `/Coolcompany`), but I think the issue preventing this from becoming the standard is that it might not always be possible to get the same URL path for each social media site (without a dispute for them).

So to answer your question:

```
Facebook.com/CoolCompany
Twitter.com/CoolCompany
...
```

Still done, but not really necessary anymore.

```
Facebook & Twitter: @CoolCompany
```

Confusing for those only familiar with Facebook, so not a good idea.

```
Facebook & Twitter: /CoolCompany
```

More commonly done with logos instead of names (and address works for both sites)

```
[Facebook logo] /CoolCompany   [Twitter logo] @CoolCompany
```

Most common and clearest to both sets of users.